# How can I prevent markers from being clipped?

Tags: buffer, mapbox

I have a series of point that I want to draw circles with varying radii around. The radii depend on the zoom level and represent a 1.1 mile circle from the point. I'm running into an issue where the circles will draw but are clipped.

All I've been able to find so far is to increase the buffer size on the source. I've maxed this out at 64 and it doesn't make a difference.

Is there any way to be able to draw markers around points with this kind of large size? Some other approach that I'm missing or another buffer I could adjust?

Comment: Why not create the 1.1 mile buffer from your points, say, in QGIS, and then bring those features into mapbox? then you don't have to worry about how large to style the points at different zoom levels.

Comment: Mostly because I don't know anything about QGIS - I'll look into it though. Thanks!